# Why does AzureMobileClient.LoginAsync(provider, token) take so long?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-mobile-services

I have a Xamarin Forms app, which consists of a PCL project, iOS, and Android.  I have implemented native login for Google and Facebook, which work fine and they return a authentication token.  However, once I receive the token, I call

```
var user = Client.LoginAsync(Google, token);
```

The request goes through, but sometimes the request takes upwards of 15seconds! 90% of my LoginAsync calls probably take 15+ seconds.  The other 10% actually work quick.  I've tried making the call in the iOS project instead of the PCL project, but it had the same result.  I've searched for performance issues dealing with AzureMobileClient but i have not found anything.  Everything appears to be correct, because eventually the request returns, but the 15+ second requests are killing my login process!  This also happens for Facebook as well.  Any suggestions?

Comment: slow network i'd assume? You're looking at the wrong end of performance. Login is done once. Who really cares if it takes a couple seconds if you visualize it?

Comment: It has taken 20+ seconds many times as well.  Something has to be wrong with it.  Shouldn't be the network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests were taking a long time throughout the app. I swapped out the MobileServiceClient for a HttpClient and everything has worked great since.  I'm not sure what kind of overhead the MobileServiceClient adds, but my app went from unusable to lightning fast.

```
        var messageHandler = new NativeMessageHandler()
        {
            Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 8),
            EnableUntrustedCertificates = true,
            DisableCaching = true

        };
        client = new HttpClient(messageHandler);
        var uri = new Uri("example");
        client.BaseAddress = uri;
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
```

Comment: Do you have any more information about how you did this?

Comment: Sure, give me a bit and I’ll answer this @Bejasc

Comment: thanks mate, I appreciate it. 
In the meantime, I also found (and am in the process of testing) the approach listed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180119120441/https://shellmonger.com/2016/06/23/using-modernhttpclient-with-azure-mobile-apps/). Not sure if this is even close to what you're doing.

Comment: That is the route i went as well, using modern http client, though you'll want to get the right version. I believe the original nuget package is outdated. Use this one here https://www.nuget.org/packages/modernhttpclient-updated/ @Bejasc

Comment: Thanks. I've tried using the package you've provided, as well as updating my `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client`, and `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore`, but I'm not seeing any improved speeds. 

The steps I took were replacing `client = new MobileServiceClient(azureURL);` with `client = new MobileServiceClient(azureURL, new ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler());`.

Is there perhaps something I'm missing?

Comment: Are you still calling any methods like `client.GetSyncTable` for storing data to the device?